# Adding Model directories to the ClassLoader

Tags: laravel, octobercms

**I am using [October](http://octobercms.com/), a CMS built on top of the [Laravel framework](http://laravel.com/).**

In October, pretty much everything is plugin based, and Models seem to be defined exclusively within `plugin/model` directories. Unfortunately, I need to define and use a number of site-wide `Models`. To that end, I have created the classic `Laravel` `app/models` directory and placed them in there.

The framework, however, does not detect these models and auto-load them. I have had success just including them in my standard `php` files, to some extent. However, when I attempt to define relationships between my models I run into problems. I think (this could be wrong) that I need to use whatever the autoload system is for `Laravel`/`October`.

I found `Illuminate\Support\ClassLoader` and tried using the `addDirectories()` method, passing in `['app/models']` in the hopes that my models would undergo the "standard" autoload process. Unfortunately, while it didn't break anything, it didn't fix anything either.

**The Question:**

How can I specify a custom directory for the Laravel application to load upon startup? Are their additional steps I need to register the `Models` I have in the aforementioned directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it to the `classmap` in your `composer.json` file:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/models"
    ]
}
```

The way it is set up in a regular Laravel install.

Comment: Is there a way to do this within PHP? Adding to composer.json requires re-building the autoload map I think. I saw someone else doing it in an old version of laravel using the ClassLoader class (part of composer) (https://github.com/msurguy/laravel-seo/blob/master/app/start/global.php), but Laravel does not seem to expose this class to us in the current version. The class is used in the php files that composer generates... I wouldn't try hacking my own solution to this if Laravel doesn't intend for you to do this.